# Python PDF integrity checking

Tags: python, pdf

I have a library of pdfs (the majority have some random compressed things and djvu's also). Some of these pdfs have become corrupted and should be deleted.

Is there anyway I can do pdf integrity checking in python?

Answer (score 4):

You could pyPDF to read the pdf and declare it invalid if the read process gives you an error... like so,

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader 
try :
     mypdf = PdfFileReader(file( 'filename', 'rb'))
except:
     print filename,' is invalid pdf'
```

Comment: ok. I'm trying that now but I was wondering if there was any other way. Also, I assume the hash of the pdf data is unique yes? (assuming no collisions)

Comment: Yes, PDF hashes should be unique.  But there are a lot of PDFs that PyPDF won't open, but most PDF readers will, so at best, this technique will give you a list of potential candidates for removal.